# image loading in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in which in first draw the div's and call image load function

In image load function i call a another function Loadimage

In Loadimage i append the image to the div's which i have drawn in first function

thumb[] has a image html tag

I have button when clicked on it a popupwindow opens,and the popupwindow has div called image in which the images are appended

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

```
for (var i in this.thumb) {          
            var img = this.thumb[i];
            var imgdiv = $('<div>');


            imgdiv.attr('id', 'img' + i + '');

            (#image).append(imgdiv);
            $(img).load({ navig_cell: img, index: i }, jQuery.proxy(this, 'Loadimage'));

}

Loadimage: function(params) {
        var img = params.data.navig_cell;
        var index = params.data.index;

        $('#img' + index + '').append(img);
}
```

Once i close the popupwindow in which i append the image and for the next time when i quickly open the popupwindow the images are appending from the place were the loading of the image stop and also the same images are append for second time from the place the loading of the images stopped(2 time the images are appending)

Comment: You've asked several questions now, with respect you should be formatting code correctly as a matter of course at this point. When you were typing your question, to the right was a handy **How to Format** box saying what to do (the *first item* is that you format code by indenting it with four spaces). Above the question box there's the **[?]** button for more information, and below the question box there's a preview area for checking that things look right.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code? As quoted, you're inadvertently creating a *label* called `Loadimage` rather than creating a function with that name or creating a property with that name on an object (e.g., in an object literal). Impossible to tell whether that's because you copied bits and pieces, or if it's really the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$('#img' + index + '').append(img);
```

This adds more images to the ones which already exist. You probably want:

```
$('#img' + index + '').html(img);
```

which replaces the current content with the new `img`.